# Making two CGRects stay together while one of them moves

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, geometry

I have a game where a ball bounces from platform to platform. I am looking to change it so that when the ball hits the platform, it does not automatically bounce, but instead it sticks to the platform, and bounces when the user tells it to. The way I have it set up right now is the following:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect (ball.frame, platform1.frame) && (UpMovement < -2)) {

     [self bounce];
     [self platformshiftdown];

}
```

Where `bounce` has the `NSArray` animation images, and `platformShiftDown` has an `int` that tells it how much to move (if that part of the code is necessary to help solve the problem).

Essentially, I want to change it so that when the ball intersects the platform's frame, it stops and "sticks" to the platform, until the user touches the bounce/jump button. I was thinking there are possibly two ways to do this:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect (ball.frame, platform1.frame)) {
        ballMovement = -2
        platformMovement = -2 
}

    //to create the illusion that the ball is stuck to the platform, because they both have the same downward movement
```

Then set up a button where the user clicks to jump/bounce off the platform. But this didn't look that great, because it the ball doesn't necessarily look like its stuck to the platform. Is there any type of code I could write that says something along the lines of "If CGRectIntersectsRect ... ball stuck ?" (obviously this isn't code, just trying to get the point across).

Comment: Why aren't you using SpriteKit?

Comment: I'm just starting out with developing, is it easy to learn? (spritekit) @duci9y

Comment: Oh yes!!! Much MUCH easier than what you are doing yourself. But if you are just starting with iOS development, I'd suggest working on something simpler than a game.

Comment: I know, it may have been a mistake to start with a game, but it's almost done now, and for the most part it's okay, just kinda working out the physics I suppose. What did you use to learn spritekit? Any good links to tutorials or any tips? @duci9y

Comment: Ray Wenderlich's introduction to SpriteKit was the only thing I read. Apart from that, Apple's documentation, whenever I needed it. And I learnt it 3 days ago, and already finished a Flappy Bird clone.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the tips. It helps being able to discuss things with someone. @duci9y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ball is likely moving strangely because it's intersecting with the platform remaining overlapped.

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect (ball.frame, platform1.frame)) {
    [self platformShiftDown];

    CGRect newRect = ball.frame;
    newRect.y = platform.frame.y + ball.frame.height;
    ball.frame = newRect;
}
```

This will move the ball exactly to the edge of the platform at all times.
If the platform moves, so will the ball.
It's also important the the platform moves first to make sure the ball stays synchronized.